# Explanation of this FizzBuzz scala implementation

Tags: scala, fizzbuzz

How does the below scala implementation of FizzBuzz work ?

Here is what I think, but im not sure if im on the right track : 
  The use of `=>` Is this a high order function, if so it is just returning a String
  `i` is a String which contains either `"FizzBuzz"` , `"Fizz"` or `"Buzz"`

```
package fizzbuzz

object FizzBuzz {
  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    (1 until 100).map(_ match {                
      case i : Int if ((i % 3) == 0 && (i % 5) == 0) => "FizzBuzz"
      case i : Int if ((i % 3) == 0) => "Fizz"
      case i : Int if ((i % 5) == 0) => "Buzz"
      case i : Int => i.toString
    }).foreach(println _)
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BrianDriscoll let me disagree with you, CR [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) clearly **prohibits** questions like this: *if your question about ... understanding code snippets...then your question is off-topic for this site*

Comment: I think this falls into the pointlessly-functional, or maybe cargo-cult functional. The match and case do nothing. `(1 until 100).map { i => { if  ((i % 3) == 0 && (i % 5) == 0) "FizzBuzz" else if ((i%3) == 0) "Fizz" else if ((i%5) == 0) "Buzz" else i.toString} }.foreach (println _)` does the job. And isn't any more imperative

Comment: i have to agree with Paul match-case with the if guards is a little too much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The use of => Is this a high order function

No, the `=>` here is part of the match-case syntax. It separates the pattern for the given case from the case's body, i.e. the syntax is `case pattern => body` where `pattern` a pattern to match against the given value and `body` is the code that's supposed to execute if `pattern` matches.

The code works by iterating over the numbers from 1 until 100 (by using map) and matching each number against the patterns in the `match` block. The patterns use pattern guards to check whether each number is divisible by 3, 5 or both (or neither). The result is a sequence of strings. The code then iterates over that sequence using `foreach` and prints each item using `println`.

Comment: why is map being used ? Can not just iterate over the items by not using map ?

Comment: @user701254 You could also iterate using for example a `while` loop, but this is written in a functional programming style. Using a loop is imperative style.

Comment: @Jesper thanks, why is the wildcard used alongside match : _ match {

Comment: @Jesper its just the variable being returned by match ?

Comment: The underscore makes the whole `_ match { ... }` into a function that's passed to `map`; it could also have been written as `x => x match { ... }`.

Comment: @Jesper So 'println _' and '_ match' are not linked in this code. 'println _' is just printing the first parameter returned by the foreach method

Comment: @user701254 Yes, the `_` after the `println` is not the same thing as the `_` before the `match`. The `_` after the `println` is indeed what `foreach` passes - like with the `match`, it could have been written as `foreach(s => println(s))`.

Comment: thanks all!, hopefully scala will start making sense to me soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
(1 to 100) map { n => (n % 3 == 0, n % 5 == 0, n) } map {
case (true, true, n) => "FizzBuzz"
case (true, false, n) => "Fizz"
case (false, true, n) => "Buzz"
case (false, false, n) => n
} foreach (println)


(1 to 100) foreach { n =>
  println( (n % 3 == 0, n % 5 == 0) match {
    case (true, true) => "FizzBuzz"
    case (true, false) => "Fizz"
    case (false, true) => "Buzz"
    case (false, false) => n
  } )
}
```